# Using a custom Rocket Responder for an error in a RequestGuard

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

In a web server application using rocket.rs, I am using an Error type that implement `Responder` throughout my API. This error type ensures all errors are uniformly rendered (as RFC 7807 json).

However, I can't find a way to use these Error responses in `RequestGuards`. It seems that the `from_request` function results in an `Outcome` which uses an entirely different model, returning `Outcome::Failure((Status, T))` on errors.

How can I ensure that errors in these request guards are rendered in the same JSON format? Is it even customizable?

I have tried to use a catcher, but this does not seem to retrieve any error information whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

The [docs for `FromRequest`'s `Outcome`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html#outcomes) state:

> Note that users can request types of `Result<S, E>` and `Option<S>` to catch `Failure`s and retrieve the error value.

1. At the start of your `FromRequest` implementation, define `type Error = JsonValue;`
2. In the `from_request` function, make sure it returns `request::Outcome<S, Self::Error>` where `S` is what you're implementing for.
3. In the `from_request` function, when you want to return a failure do something like `Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, json!({"error": "unauthorised"})))`, or whatever it is you want to return.
4. In your route's function use `Result<S, JsonValue>` as the type of the request guard, where `S` is what you where implementing for. In your route, use `match` to match it to `Ok(S)` or `Err(json_error)` for example.

There is probably a way to pass on the status of `Outcome::Failure`, but the solution I've described means if you're using a custom responder you would set the status in the responder, not based on `Outcome::Failure` - for example the code below.

Here's an example applied to the `ApiKey` request guard example from the docs, with an example custom responder called `ApiResponse` that sets its own status:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use rocket::Outcome;
use rocket::http::{ContentType, Status};
use rocket::request::{self, Request, FromRequest};
use rocket::response::{self, Responder, Response};
use rocket_contrib::json::{Json, JsonValue};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ApiResponse {
    pub json: JsonValue,
    pub status: Status,
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r> for ApiResponse {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &Request) -> response::Result<'r> {
        Response::build_from(self.json.respond_to(req).unwrap())
            .status(self.status)
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .ok()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct ApiKey(String);

/// Returns true if `key` is a valid API key string.
fn is_valid(key: &str) -> bool {
    key == "valid_api_key"
}

impl<'a, 'r> FromRequest<'a, 'r> for ApiKey {
    type Error = JsonValue;

    fn from_request(request: &'a Request<'r>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let keys: Vec<_> = request.headers().get("x-api-key").collect();
        match keys.len() {
            0 => Outcome::Failure((Status::BadRequest, json!({ "error": "api key missing" }))),
            1 if is_valid(keys[0]) => Outcome::Success(ApiKey(keys[0].to_string())),
            1 => Outcome::Failure((Status::BadRequest, json!({ "error": "api key invalid" }))),
            _ => Outcome::Failure((Status::BadRequest, json!({ "error": "bad api key count" }))),
        }
    }
}

#[get("/sensitive")]
fn sensitive(key: Result<ApiKey, JsonValue>) -> ApiResponse {
    match key {
        Ok(_ApiKey) => ApiResponse {
            json: json!({ "data": "sensitive data." }),
            status: Status::Ok
        },
        Err(json_error) => ApiResponse {
            json: json_error,
            status: Status::BadRequest
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Rust and Rocket, so this might not be the best solution.